# detect response body encoding with nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I am writing a spider with jsdom and jQuery like [the example](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/README.md)

There's just one problem: When the web page is not UTF-8 encoded and response header's content-type does not tell me the charset, how do I detect the encoding of the response body?

I know node-iconv can help, but the problem is I need to know the encoding first

(Bonus question: How does web browsers auto detect the encoding of a web page?)

Answer (score 0):

npm install node-ice-charset-detector

https://github.com/mooz/node-icu-charset-detector